# Best practice to "Remove Ads" from Android free app

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I've a free Android app and I need to enable user to buy the app by hitting remove ads button. what is the best practice?

Questions:-

1-What is the best practice of converting free Android app to paid app? do I need to generate a new application with different package name?

2-What are recommended libraries/code to be included on top of free app to be paid app?

3-How to guarantee downloaded paid apk from out side google play will not work? and force user to buy the app from google play?

Answer (score 1):

When I built an app, I did a separate build and uploaded a separate paid app without the ads. I regret this choice. IMO, going with in-app billing instead would be better.

Comment: Having done both, an in-app purchase was definitely better, both for easier development and for easier upgrades for users of the app.